# How to create term set in managed metadata service?

Tags: managed-metadata

I am trying to do managed navigation in my SharePoint site, but when I click on create term set I get an error:

> Failed to create term set: A default managed metadata service connection hasn't been specified.

I have already started managed metadata service and set default proxy group in central admin. When I click on managed metadata service connection properties then again I get:

> There are no addresses available for this application

Kindly help me.

Comment: Have you seen http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44238/issues-setting-up-the-managed-metadata-service and http://sureshpydi.blogspot.in/2013/04/there-are-no-addresses-available-for.html?

Comment: Check the following link, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23388.sharepoint-2013-failed-to-create-term-set-a-default-managed-metadata-service-connection-hasnt-been-specified.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the below path  and check your  managed meta data service has started / stopped 
      Central Administration -> manage Services on server -> Managed metadata service).If  It is stopped then Restart the service

If it is not clear follow the below links,
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/allenwang/archive/2011/03/22/the-managed-metadata-or-connection-is-currently-not-available.aspx

http://sharepointroot.com/2011/01/11/the-managed-metadata-service-or-connection-is-currently-not-available/

http://sureshpydi.blogspot.in/2013/04/there-are-no-addresses-available-for.html

Comment: thanks for your help.for my requirement its very useful..

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to make sure.

- check if the MMS service is associated with the Central admin. central admin> Application management > manage web application> click on central admin and from Ribbon click on service connection. Make sure MMS is associated with it.
- check the app pool of MMS from the Server where this service is running.
- Restart the MMS service from the services on server.
- if you have multiple server in the farm, then try to start the service on the different server.

Comment: Its still not working. Actually I am trying to do dynamic drop down global navigation menu same as column. Is I am going wrong way or correct? Kindly suggest me how to achieve this drop down menu.